# grep syntax issue on Lion

Tags: terminal

I have a text file and looking for the single line `bird`. Using OS X Lion and grep 2.5.1.

this works:

```
grep '^bird' file.txt
```

but this doesn't

```
grep '^bird$' file.txt
```

There is not a blank space at the end of the line. What am I doing wrong?

thx

Comment: Works for me. Just one very long shot: You search `enable1.txt` in variant 1 and `file.txt` in variant 2.

Comment: looks like CRLF updated to file.txt

Answer (score 5):

Its usually because of a DOS formatted text file (CRLF). To clean the file you can install a tooö like `dos2unix`; but usually works even simpler by using the `tr` tool:

```
tr -d '\r' < testfile > output.txt
```

Comment: Agreed, that should work pretty much anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing it's a CRLF file (dos formatted text file)

```
[bob@erasmas tmp]$ cat testfile
bird
notbird
[bob@erasmas tmp]$ cat testfile.dos
bird
notbird
[bob@erasmas tmp]$ file testfile
testfile: ASCII text
[bob@erasmas tmp]$ file testfile.dos
testfile.dos: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
[bob@erasmas tmp]$ grep '^bird' testfile
bird
[bob@erasmas tmp]$ grep '^bird' testfile.dos
bird
[bob@erasmas tmp]$ grep '^bird$' testfile
bird
[bob@erasmas tmp]$ grep '^bird$' testfile.dos
```

Note:  This was on a Linux machine, as this is not specific to OS X (if this is infact the problem).

Run "file" on file.txt and see if it has CRLF line endings.

Comment: this is corect. `file.txt: ASCII c program text, with CRLF line terminators` - any idea how to check. seems like grep should handle this...

Comment: looks like this did it `sed 's/.$//'  file.txt > fixed.txt`

Comment: That sed statement removes ANY character at the end of a line, which might unintentionally clean away too much if you're unlucky. But as always with *NIX; loads of way to do the same thing. See my answer below for another way to clean it up. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the MS-DOS formatting, then you can insert the MS-DOS carriage return within the pattern. On linux I press CTRL-V CTRL-M to produce the literal `^M` representing the MS-DOS CR (sometimes noted as `\r`). Hope on OS X you will find how to produce the literal CR.

```
grep --color=none "^bird^M$"
```